# Creating QGIS Symbology Database?

Tags: qgis, symbology, database

I'm looking to swap from MapInfo to QGIS at my work and im trying to see if its possbile to have a centralised symbology database. eg to be able to pull our symbology from a database rather than from within the layer itself.

From what i've been able to figure out so far is that we could store the symbology for all our various layers in either an XML or a geodatabase and them import to the asset layers in question from there via postgis connection a file or url.

Has anyone had to do something like this in the past?

Comment: We're saving frequently used symbologies as `.qml` in a central folder, everyone has access to.

Comment: If your layer comes from a database, in the layer properties, you can choose to save the style into the database, is-it enough or are you looking something else?

Comment: I think thatd be the way we're heading towards. We're hoping to be able to have a central location for our symbology for our layers to call from. Is there a best way to do that or is it a case of six and two threes?